# Duplicating Angular response data so changes to one don't affect the other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have an angular controller connected to a node/express server. Response data for a request is called in an `$http.get` where I can set `response=$scope.x`. `x` can then be interacted with and changed. I could then set `$scope.y = $scope.x`, and any changes to `y` would result in `x` changing as well. However, I basically want to clone the response so as to have the original response data set to different variables without them changing each other.

Consider a response where `response.name = "Joe"`.

```
$scope.x = response;
$scope.y = response;
```

In my code or view/model I could change `x.name` as such:

```
$scope.x.name = "Bob"
```

However, I would like `$scope.y.name` to still equal `"Joe"`.

I could use two separate get requests to retrieve the same response, but I'd like to pass the response into a function which will dynamically change that data and make a new version of it based on a `for` loop. Is there a clean, "angular" to do this? Or a simple javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular has a built in utility for this `angular.copy()`

```
$scope.x = response;
$scope.y = angular.copy(response);
```

Can also be used to clean out unwanted properties that angular can create such as hashkeys used in `ng-repeat` tracking

[angular.copy() docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is

`$scope.y = angular.copy($scope.x)`

or

`$scope.y =_.clone($scope.x)`

if you are using lodash/underscore.

---

The long answer, unfortunately is longer, and necessitates you learning about the difference between byReference and byValue variable types.
To understand it please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).